# System cannot find path/command not found error in Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, elasticsearch

I have an installation of Elasticsearch that has worked fine for months but has inexplicably gone missing according to Powershell. The only thing I can think of that has changed recently is that I updated Java.

When I try to run it using the full path I get the following error:

```
PS C:\> C:\elasticsearch\bin\elasticsearch.bat
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

The path exists and there is no spelling error as you can see here:

```
PS C:\elasticsearch\bin> dir

    Directory: C:\elasticsearch\bin

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         8/7/2016  10:13 PM           5551 elasticsearch
-a----         8/7/2016  10:13 PM         104448 elasticsearch-service-mgr.exe
-a----         8/7/2016  10:13 PM         103936 elasticsearch-service-x64.exe
-a----         8/7/2016  10:13 PM          80896 elasticsearch-service-x86.exe
-a----         8/7/2016  10:13 PM            909 elasticsearch.bat
-a----         8/7/2016  10:13 PM           3307 elasticsearch.in.bat
-a----         8/7/2016  10:13 PM           2814 elasticsearch.in.sh
-a----         8/7/2016  10:13 PM           2992 plugin
-a----         8/7/2016  10:13 PM           1303 plugin.bat
-a----         8/7/2016  10:13 PM           6501 service.bat
```

When I try to run it from within the directory itself, I get the following message:

```
PS C:\elasticsearch\bin> elasticsearch.bat
elasticsearch.bat : The term 'elasticsearch.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ elasticsearch.bat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (elasticsearch.bat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Suggestion [3,General]: The command elasticsearch.bat was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows Pow
erShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\elastic
search.bat". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
```

I don't have a strong knowledge of handling Powershell errors, so I have only tried a few things:

1. Reinstalling Elasticsearch
2. Adding the directory containing elasticsearch.bat to the path
3. Running elasticsearch.bat using the command ./elasticsearch.bat

None of these change anything.

Here's the content of elasticsearch.bat:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
TITLE Elasticsearch 2.3.5

SET params='%*'

:loop
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims= " %%A IN (!params!) DO (
    SET current=%%A
    SET params='%%B'
    SET silent=N

    IF "!current!" == "-s" (
        SET silent=Y
    )
    IF "!current!" == "--silent" (
        SET silent=Y
    )   

    IF "!silent!" == "Y" (
        SET nopauseonerror=Y
    ) ELSE (
        IF "x!newparams!" NEQ "x" (
            SET newparams=!newparams! !current!
        ) ELSE (
            SET newparams=!current!
        )
    )

    IF "x!params!" NEQ "x" (
        GOTO loop
    )
)

SET HOSTNAME=%COMPUTERNAME%

CALL "%~dp0elasticsearch.in.bat"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    IF NOT DEFINED nopauseonerror (
        PAUSE
    )
    EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
)

"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" %JAVA_OPTS% %ES_JAVA_OPTS% %ES_PARAMS% -cp "%ES_CLASSPATH%" "org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch" start !newparams!

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: cough read the error message "*Suggestion [3,General]: The command elasticsearch.bat was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\elastic
search.bat". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details."* No idea why the first one doesn't work, possibly something in the batch file references a java.exe which has moved? What's in the batch file?

Comment: I did indeed try the suggestion in the error message, i.e., run .\elasticsearch.bat from the bin directory and all I get is "The system cannot find the path specified." I will post the content of the .bat file above. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PS C:\> C:\elasticsearch\bin\elasticsearch.bat
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Are you sure that's not *the output of the batch file*?  In other words, something in the batch file cannot find a path specified (perhaps `java.exe`).  If PowerShell can't find the file, you'll get an error message like your second attempt.

Speaking of your second attempt:

```
PS C:\elasticsearch\bin> elasticsearch.bat
```

As the error message states, this won't work for files in the current folder.  You need to explicitly specify the current folder:

```
PS C:\elasticsearch\bin> .\elasticsearch.bat
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try the .\elasticsearch.bat command, which returned a cannot find path message. So perhaps your first suggestion is on target. I posted the content of the .bat file above. I don't have experience reading these files. Are the items at the very bottom the problem, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, you were right. Elasticsearch.bat couldn't find Java after I updated the latter. In the .bat file posted at the end of my question, I changed "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\java" and it is now working.